# Truffle test promise that expectedly throws error

Tags: testrpc, testing, truffle-contract

I have contract with methods that check input parameters using `require(bool)` so if at least on of conditions does not matched it throws an error. During test procedure (using Truffle and Chaijs) it looks like:

```
 Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
  at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:37022:16)
  at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:210096:36
  at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:208875:13)
  at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:210748:18)
  at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:211038:12)
  at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:211193:12)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:211153:24)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
```

Test uses promises like this:

```
return MyToken.deployed().then(inst => {
  instance = inst;
  return instance.purchase({from: accounts[1], value: amount});
})....
```

Problem is that I cannot handle this exception. I tried to wrap `purchase` call into function and use `assert.throws(executor, message)` - it does not works (suppose due it expects something synchronous).

How this promise can be tested (preferably without adding `chai-as-promised`)?

Comment: Promises has a `catch` that gets called when the promise fails. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571328/how-do-i-properly-test-promises-with-mocha-and-chai .

Comment: @Ismael it does not works in tests as you expecting (I mean using Chaijs `assert.throws`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You can `catch` a promise when it was rejected before further processing.</s> Catch doesn'y work in the example because it will catch any other error not only the transaction failure.

You can use the second parameter to `then` to catch a promise being rejected before further processing, ie `MyPromise.then(() => { /* check when succeed */ }, () => { /* check when failure */ })`

```
contract('MyToken', (accounts) => {
  it("Should fail", () => {
    return MyToken.deployed().then((instance) => {
      return instance.purchase({ from: accounts[1], value: amount });
    }).then(() => {
      assert.ok(false, "It didn't fail");
    }, () => {
      assert.ok(true, "Passed");
    });
  });
});
```

Promises do not throws that is why `assert.throws` fails.

**Note after Byzantium**: Also I should mention that after the Byzantium fork some operations that previously generated a throw will no longer do such thing. Check this post so you can update your test for that fact: [How do I detect a failed transaction after the Byzantium fork as the REVERT opcode does not consume all gas?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28077/how-do-i-detect-a-failed-transaction-after-the-byzantium-fork-as-the-revert-opco)

---

Perhaps a better approach is using async/await, and `assert.throws`.

The trick is convert the promise to something not async that `assert.throws` can report. Firs a helper function

```
async function verifyThrows(pred, message) {
  let e;
  try {
    await pred();
  } catch (ex) {
    e = ex;
  }
  assert.throws(() => {
    if (e) { throw e; }
  }, message);
}
```

And we can use the helper function passing the promise execution in a function

```
contract('MyToken', (accounts) => {
  it("Should fail", async () => {
    const instance = await MyToken.deployed();
    await verifyThrows(() => {
      instance.purchase({ from: accounts[1], value: amount });
    }, /revert/);
  })
});
```

Comment: It does not works. First assert throws an error that caught in `catch` section.

Comment: @AlexG.P. You are correct. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use my truffle-assertions library to test Solidity function errors, such as invalid opcode errors or reverts.

It can be installed with npm:

```
npm install truffle-assertions
```

And then imported at the top of your file:

```
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');
```

You can then use it inside your test file like this:

```
return MyToken.deployed().then(inst => {
    instance = inst;
    truffleAssert.fails(
        instance.purchase({ from: accounts[1], value: amount }),
        truffleAssert.ErrorType.INVALID_OPCODE
    );
});
```