# How do I detect a failed transaction after the Byzantium fork as the REVERT opcode does not consume all gas?

Tags: transactions, out-of-gas, revert-opcode, byzantium

Pre Byzantium fork, I could use `gas == gasUsed` to detect when a transaction has failed (further details in [How can the transaction status from a thrown error be detected when gas can be exactly the same as the gasUsed for a successful transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/how-can-the-transaction-status-from-a-thrown-error-be-detected-when-gas-can-be-e))

Post Byzantium fork, the revert opcode now returns a much lower gasUsed amount. How do I detect a failed transaction after the Byzantium fork?

See also:

- [Difference between require and assert and the difference between revert and throw](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15166/difference-between-require-and-assert-and-the-difference-between-revert-and-thro?rq=1)
- [What improvements will the upcoming Byzantium fork bring to Smart Contract development?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27947/what-improvements-will-the-upcoming-byzantium-fork-bring-to-smart-contract-devel)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### Summary

After the Byzantium fork, `eth.getTransactionReceipt(...)` will return a `status` field. The status field has a value of `0` when a transaction has failed with the `REVERT` opcode and `1` when the transaction has succeeded.

#### Update Oct 10 2017

Responding to the comment by @thomas-jay-rush, when a transaction fails for a reason other than `REVERT` (i.e. `THROW`), the status field will have a value of `0` and `gasUsed` will be equal to `gas`. See tx [0xa0a5e34b](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa0a5e34b9b19b398c5a073513ecb461899ceb45246f51e6d470ae0cf23b39075) as an example.

---

### Details

I have configured the Byzantium block number in my dev blockchain using the following `genesis.json`:

```
{
  "config": {
    "homesteadBlock": 1,
    "byzantiumBlock": 12
  },
  "nonce": "0",
  "difficulty": "0x400",
  "mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp": "0x00",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "extraData": "0x",
  "gasLimit": "0x3B4A1B44",
  "alloc": {
    "0xa00af22d07c87d96eeeb0ed583f8f6ac7812827e": {
      "balance": "10000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "0xa11aae29840fbb5c86e6fd4cf809eba183aef433": {
      "balance": "10000000000000000000000000"
    }
  }
}
```

I can see the Byzantium fork is active in the following `geth` message:

> INFO [10-09|23:30:37] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID:  Homestead: 1 DAO:  DAOSupport: false EIP150:  EIP155:  EIP158:  Byzantium: 12 Engine: unknown}"

#### Failing Transactions Have A Transaction Receipt `status` Of `0x0`

Here is the transaction receipt information from a failing transaction with the `REVERT` opcode:

```
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x6c039439191ed046f8d4a92734bb6c23b92c175df39ce2f089ac84c590b94918")
{
  blockHash: "0xf25b938c85772aa0abbbc9931e6da7a6e46c577619fb5004f2d85fdbe359eb60",
  blockNumber: 89,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 35983,
  from: "0xa11aae29840fbb5c86e6fd4cf809eba183aef433",
  gasUsed: 35983,
  ...
  status: "0x0",
  to: "0x0e946b999033257976aa5cbe0e3530618ca1582d",
  transactionHash: "0x6c039439191ed046f8d4a92734bb6c23b92c175df39ce2f089ac84c590b94918",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

The same `status: "0x0"` is returned when executing a `throw` instruction compiled with Solidity 0.4.11 .

#### Successful Transactions Have A Transaction Receipt `status` Of `0x1`

And here is the transaction receipt information from a successful transaction:

```
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xbdacfebf6299a260adfa993421aeb26353aa2b4dd0e6f290d2acfd6a9b828a62")

{
  blockHash: "0xbda8b2d2850306e8a02be074f11ffe4f2243003df6e9c4adb1bbdcda1faf2e42",
  blockNumber: 87,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 126952,
  from: "0xa11aae29840fbb5c86e6fd4cf809eba183aef433",
  gasUsed: 126952,
  logs: [{
      address: "0x0e946b999033257976aa5cbe0e3530618ca1582d",
      blockHash: "0xbda8b2d2850306e8a02be074f11ffe4f2243003df6e9c4adb1bbdcda1faf2e42",
      blockNumber: 87,
      data: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000",
      logIndex: 0,
      removed: false,
      topics: ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef", "0x000000000000000000000000a33a6c312d9ad0e0f2e95541beed0cc081621fd0", "0x000000000000000000000000a55a151eb00fded1634d27d1127b4be4627079ea"],
      transactionHash: "0xbdacfebf6299a260adfa993421aeb26353aa2b4dd0e6f290d2acfd6a9b828a62",
      transactionIndex: 0
  }, {
    ...
  }],
  ...
  status: "0x1",
  to: "0x0e946b999033257976aa5cbe0e3530618ca1582d",
  transactionHash: "0xbdacfebf6299a260adfa993421aeb26353aa2b4dd0e6f290d2acfd6a9b828a62",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

`eth.getTransactionReceipt(...)` pre-Byzantium fork does not include the `status` field.

#### Can The Status Be Anything Other Than Than Just 0 (Fail) And 1 (Success)?

From https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/receipt.go#L39-L42:

- `ReceiptStatusFailed = uint(0)`
- `ReceiptStatusSuccessful = uint(1)`

There is only be a status of failed (=0) or successful (=1).

See [EIP 658: Embedding transaction return data in receipts](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/658) for further information.

#### How Does EtherScan Currently Handle The Byzantium Fork Status On Ropsten?

Here's a transaction that is successfully executed - [0x142b8830](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x142b88304c4fe6cf7ab26d7dd6af89a77e9e19141bf3edc189480224c6407dd4)

And here's a transaction that has failed using the `REVERT` opcode - [0x67a5f644](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x67a5f6442f49a5da6ff8682250a8eef899d9dc0c5adf20b683709433902b5956)

The failed transaction cannot be distinguished from the successful transaction in EtherScan currently, except that the failed transaction consumed less gas than the successful transaction, and the failed transaction did not log an event but the successful transaction did.

I've pinged EtherScan about this potential issue.

**Update Oct 15 2017** There is now a **TxReceipt Status:** field on the EtherScan transaction page that displays **Success** or **Fail**.

Comment: Etherscan now supports this in the Byzantium activated ropsten: https://twitter.com/LefterisJP/status/917888899141300224

Comment: Nice! The txs I posted above have the blank TxReceipt Status fields. But it's there and should be good for new txs scanned by EtherScan.

Comment: We are reindexing the previous transactions, once this is completed it should show up on ropsten

Comment: Just checked it and the Fail is now displayed for my failed tx. Great.

Comment: There's something missing here. Maybe it just needs to be clarified. It says "The status field has a value of 0 when a transaction has failed with the REVERT opcode and 1 when the transaction has succeeded." This is silent about what happens when a transaction fails for reasons other than a REVERT (such as a THROW). Does status == 0 on a THROW as well as a REVERT or just a REVERT which is what this says.

Comment: Added info about status from a THROW. Thx @TJR

Answer (score 0):

Hate to tell you - but sometimes the used gas and the supplied gas are the same and it succeeded.

Can't remember which, think it was Parity - where the estimates are 100% accurate.

Comment: Yup. Details in https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/how-can-the-transaction-status-from-a-thrown-error-be-detected-when-gas-can-be-e

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with estimates. Even if the estimates were 100% accurate there would still be cases where gasUsed == gasAllowed ended in sucessfull transaction due to the simple fact that the exact same amount of gas was actually used as was supplied. For example in every simple transfer of ether from one external account to another where most wallets allow 21000 and exactly 21000 is consumed.

Comment: I think that is what I said....