# What does it mean to have a failed TxReceipt Status?

Tags: blockchain, ether

I realize this is probably a noob question so please forgive me, but what does it mean to have a failed TxReceipt?

So for instance: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x54f66e0c91b380b4779e92a8f0475663aa764f1c196bf98ec35fa5f11e4c0eea

I mean, it's obviously part of the chain, but it implys that because something failed, the value gets reverted? What exactly failed here? Because it certainly deducted the value from the origin address, that sure didn't fail.

Comment: Duplicate? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28889/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-a-transactions-new-receipt-status-field

Comment: Same problem, in my contract there was a `require` statement not passed. Maybe you should review your smart contract code. Actually, the value was not transferred, just spent some gas.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, a failed transaction to a contract address means that some modifier or require(...) did not hold, and therefore the whole transaction was reverted.

If you look closely, the ethers were actually not taken, as it says [CANCELLED].

Actually, by looking at the empty data field of that transaction, I assume this address was calling the default callback function of the contract or that maybe you did not properly called the desired function of the contract, but instead the contract itself, and therefore it failed WITHOUT CHARGING THE SENT ETHERS.

Hope this helped. Try to be more specific if it did not.

Comment: So I think I understand why it failed, I was supposed to send at least 0.01 eth and I failed to do so. But the total eth in the source address is as if the charge did happen, which I suppose is my point, it returned the eth in name (or status) only and nothing is recognizing that.