# Difference between `0x01` and `0x1` status code?

Tags: web3js, transactions, blockchain, ganache

Sometimes when running Ganache I receive status code `0x01`, sometimes `0x1`. Should I treat both as successful executions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There's no difference between 0x01 and 0x1**. In hexadecimal notation 0x1, 0x01, 0x001, and so on, they all means 1. About transaction's status code, if it is set to 1 it always means a successful execution. Check [this question/answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28889/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-a-transactions-new-receipt-status-field) for more details.